# How do I conditionally render data returned from a useEffect that calls an API route and adds that data to a useState variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a React component that's main purpose is to display a list of profile names. The profile names are stored in a useState variable called profiles.

I have a useEffect in place on the component that effectively calls our API route to return the profile data we need on the frontend and place that data in the state variable for profiles.

If the profiles state variable has a length of zero, then we don't have the data and a logo will appear to load, otherwise the profiles should be mapped through and displayed as h1 tags.

While a console.log shows to me I am returning the data I need, I am getting the following error in my console "Uncaught TypeError: profiles.map is not a function".

Here is my code:

```
function ProfileListComponent() {

    const fetchProfiles = async (payload) => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
        const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/profiles", {headers:{
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }})
        if (response.data) {
            let profileData = []
            for (let key in response.data) {
                let profile = [
                    response.data[key].profile_id,
                    response.data[key].profile_name,
                    response.data[key].flow_rate,
                    response.data[key].hv,
                    response.data[key].lv,
                    response.data[key].duty_cycle,
                    response.data[key].frequency,  
                ]
                profileData.push(profile)
            }
            console.log(profileData)
            return profileData
        }
    }

    const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([])

    const compileProfileData = () => {
        return ""
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            const profileData = fetchProfiles()
            setProfiles(profileData)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {profiles.length === 0 ?
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        : (
            profiles.map(profile => <h1 className="profileBox" key={profile[0]} onClick={() => {compileProfileData(profile)}}>{profile[1]}</h1>
                    )
        )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried different methods to conditionally render this data, though I always seem to error out with the same message indicating that the state variable isn't even an array (which is interesting considering its default value is an empty array).

Does anyone have some guidance to offer on how to correctly get this data rendered?

Comment: can you show what it logs with `console.log(profiles)` ?

Comment: Sure thing! 

(26) [Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7)]

0: (7) [52, 'UltimatePower', 9, 4, 8, 4, 5]
(the remaining arrays are displayed in the same fashion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because inside `useEffect` hook `try-catch` block executes both `fetchProfiles` and `setProfiles` synchronously. So `setProfiles` sets a promise which has not resulted yet and below map function means `"Give me array, not a promise"`.You should put your `setState` inside fetchProfiles.

From this;

```js
const fetchProfiles = async () => {
    // const profileData = await axios ...
    return profileData;
};

useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const data = fetchProfiles();
      setProfiles(data); // SETS HERE
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}, []);
```

To this;

```js
const fetchProfiles = async () => {
    // const profileData = await axios ...
    setProfiles(profileData); // SETS HERE
};

useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const data = fetchProfiles();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}, []);
```

Imagine `profileData` is constant mock data. And you can try this at
[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zu5avk?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Ahh this makes sense, thank you so much for the description as to why this was failing! The clarity is greatly appreciated and I am happy to report that this is now functioning as intended. Thanks again!